# Good approach to resize internet images using screen density?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am fetching large images from the API which need to be resized to fit different screen types.

Is is a good approach to resize them by multiplying MDPI resolution with screen density?

I've implemented this approach and tested it and so far it works. I am wondering if this is a good approach which I can apply to the whole project.

So if MDPI size is 100px which looks OK on MDPI screens, I will resize images for other types using `MDPI_SIZE * getScreenDensity()` where the later method looks like

```
public static float getScreenDensity(Context context) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return metrics.density;
}
```

So image size on XHDPI would be 200dp, on XXHDPI 300dp, etc. All of course, set programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I use something very similar to this (but for **svg graphics**, which is **vectorial**).
Of course, your images need to be in a good resolution for mdpi, to scale with this system.

BUT! You better scale **DOWN**, for better quality results.
Or a 1*1 pixel in mdpi would be scaled to a 3*3 pixels in xxhdpi.

So, you better download the images which fit for an xxhdpi screen and then scale them down.
And your scale factor will be **0.667** for xhdpi, **0.5** for hdpi, **0.333** for mdpi, **0.25** for ldpi.

Comment: Yes, I am scaling down. Otherwise, the result on XXHDPI would be horrible. Thanks

Comment: So your scale factor will be **0.667** for xhdpi, **0.5** for hdpi, **0.333** for mdpi, **0.25** for ldpi.

Comment: Got it. This logic is only user to determine the size. So large image of 1024x0124px would be downsized each time for specific resolution.